# Python: returning item list under class function

Tags: python

I am python beginner and have a question..

I have a class function looks like:

```
class Example(A):
    def __init__(self, ID, name, products, itemlist):
        A.__init__(self, itemID, name)
        self.products = products
        self.itemlist = itemlist
    def get_items_list(self):
        return self.itemlist
```

Assume I have written

```
Example('SomeID', 'Somename', products, [('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1)])
```

then when I do

```
get_items_list()
```

My code returns

```
bound method Compound.get_items_str of SomeID, Somename, <__main__.Products object at 0x102d2e4d0>>
```

instead of the item list I provided...

Any answers would be so appreciated and excuse for my mistakes.

Comment: The code you've put up here couldn't have produced the error you're getting. That said, in your actual code you probably left off parens on a method call.

Comment: Surely this should produce: `NameError: name 'get_items_list' is not defined`...

Comment: By the way what's itemID passed to A initialization? In the code you showed us it's simply not declared.

Comment: Style recommendation: You should do `super(Example, self).__init__(itemID, name)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you didn't call the method like in this question.

check your code and see if there is a

```
youclass.get_items_list
```

instead of a

```
yourclass.get_items_list()
```

Comment: or like is claimed in the question `get_items_list()` (!)

Comment: huh? what do you mean? you can't call that function without the instanciated class in front.

Comment: that does not work and does not mean anything. please explain what your trying to do and show all the code you have.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put it this way:

```
>>> example_instance = Example('SomeID', 'Somename', products, [('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1)])
>>> example_instance.get_items_list()
```

By the way I suggest looking into the [Python documentation about classes](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html)